# cat sits on me as I sleep

Tags: cats

It occurs to me belatedly to blame my morning backaches not on any deficiency in the (new) mattress but on the weight of a cat (age 10) who likes to perch on my flank.  How can I discourage that, short of excluding him and his brother from their favorite room?

Comment: Do you wake up when they take place?

Comment: @Allerleirauh If I did, it would be less of a problem!

Comment: Honestly, it's probably your mattress. I routinely wake up with 10-22 lbs (4.5-10 kg) of cat sleeping on top of me, but I have a good mattress and have no issues. Previously, with a different cat and mattress, I would occasionally have a 10 lb cat sleep on me, but would always wake up unable to move, because the mattress was worn out and no longer offering support.

Comment: Do you gloat? Not all of us have pets that sleeps on us!

Comment: If you want to see if this is the mattress or the cat, get a heated blanket and place it on the bed next to you. The cat will prefer to lay there, then you can see if your back feels better in the morning or not. Even a small heating pad will work, although the smaller pads usually shut off after a couple hours (and the cat may migrate to a warmer body).